# Comparing AJAX Treeview & GridControls from different vendors. Whose is better?

Tags: ajax, datagrid, datagridview, grid

I've been working exclusively with ComponentArt controls and want to know what else is out there.  What Grid and Treeview controls are worth investigating?

It doesn't matter if I need to pay for them... quality, speed, and reliability are key.

I've seen a few issues with the CA Grid Control has issues with setting the column width dynamically, and documentation is spotty.  However it has a single programming model with the SOA offering.  Are there better options out there?

Answer (score 1):

Try [dhtmlx Grid](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/index.shtml?mn) and [dhtmlx TreeGrid](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/index.shtml?mn) , although these are javascript components we have used them with asp.net and find them to be very fast and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

[jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) is a nice AJAX-enabled grid written in JavaScript that has worked out well for me in several recent projects.

[jQuery treeView](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/) looks like a bare-bones treeview that may be worth investigating, although I have not used it on any projects so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Telerik's AJAX/Silverlight grids for my web apps and I am pretty content with them. The components are flexible and designed with the idea of rich set of features without compromising the overall performance. If you want to have a look at their online examples, go [here](http://www.telerik.com/support/demos.aspx).

Dick